# How to use jsf primefaces to display table taken with criteria taken from search form

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 5.2
JSF 2.0.11 
WebLogic 10.3.6 
Java 1.6

I'm making a site with a search form. Depending on what is entered in the search form, a SQL query is made in a servlet, and a List of a structure I call Rows is returned to the servlet with the results of the query.

I'm trying to use Primefaces to display this List of Rows, but am having some trouble.  This is my first time using beans.  I'm not exactly sure how to do it.  Should I return the List of Rows to the servlet, pass that into the jsf page, then pass that in the bean?  Not sure how these beans work.

Comment: I think you have to take a break, a step back and start with some basic jsf tutorials. See the jsf info page for this. You seem to be mixing technogies in a way they were never intended to.

Comment: @Kukeltje yeah that's what I'm going to do. I was told at first to use jstl, and I had it working. Then they wanted me to switch it to jsf.  Not a very easy transition when you've never used jsf or beans before. Wasted too much time trying to jump into it.